# Не возвращает массив

Tags: php, база-данных, sqlite3

getNews() не возвращает массив, в чем может проблема?

```
class NewsDB implements INewsDB {
  private function db2arr($arrRow) {
    $arr = [];
    while ($row = $arrRow->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      $arr[] = $row;
    return $arr;
  }
  function getNews() {
    $sql = "SELECT msgs.id as id, title, category.name as category,
                   description, source, datetime
                              FROM msgs, category
                              WHERE category.id = msgs.category
                              ORDER BY msgs.id DESC";
    $res = $this->_db->query($sql);
    if (!$res) return false;
    return $this->db2arr($res);
  }
```

Comment: ошибка в запросе как я понял

Comment: ну так отловите что там за ошибка.

Comment: @Naumov не подскажите как? Я просто совсем новичок, убираю из запроса WHERE category.id = msgs.category ORDER BY msgs.id DESC" и появляется массив

Comment: в общемпогуглите pdo exception плюс у вас собственно msgs.category не определено в селекте

Comment: @Naumov делаю абсолютно все точно так же, как в видеоуроке. Там работает, у менят. Проверял вплоть до запятой.